# Using my weka classifier in MOA

Tags: classification, weka, new-operator, moa

I have created my own classifier in weka and it works fine with the weka gui.
I am trying to use it in [MOA](http://moa.cs.waikato.ac.nz/) by choosing weka classifier and then my classifier. My classifier appears in the MOA gui under weka classifiers but if i choose it i get a "Problems with option: baseLearner" error.
Is it not possible to use my new weka classifier in MOA, are there any path or reference to my classifier that i should add in MOA?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy to use any Weka classifier in MOA. The problem may be that MOA is not finding your classifier when it tries to build it. Try to modify the Java classpath, so that MOA can access your classifier.